# python 2.7.13 doesn't launch interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I launch python 2.7.13 I get

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500
64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

and it immediately exits.

I had expected

```
>>>
```

and for it to wait for me to enter something, just like every other version I've used.

I installed python-2.7.13.amd64.msi from python.org.

How can I fix this?

Edit: this problem seems specific to 2.7.13 x64 on Windows. Solution in comments.

Comment: the installer file has `64` in the name like, [python-2.7.13.amd**64**.msi](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/python-2.7.13.amd64.msi)? Maybe run [MD5 Sum](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889768/how-to-compute-the-md5-or-sha-1-cryptographic-hash-values-for-a-file) check on the file you installed.

Comment: @downshift Filename corrected. Oops!  md5 is correct.

Comment: Hm, well...not sure, but checkout [this bug tracker report](https://bugs.python.org/issue29037) where it talks about checking version of, and possibly upgrading `pyreadline`

Comment: @downshift upgrading `pyreadline` fixed it. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline  Thanks!

Comment: Cool glad that fixed it, cheers!